# error 500 with Call to a member function on bool

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

I am using Fat Free Framework but I got this error when trying to check non-existent data ID with `dry()` function
my code below will throw **Call to a member function dry() on bool** error if I supply it with non-existent ID value. It should echo the Empty Cursor echo if the ID not found instead if the error. If I use an ID that is within the database, it will show the id exist.

```
if(is_numeric($param['id'])) 
        {
            $id = $param['id'];
            //check if data exist
            $data = $data->load($id);
            if(!$data->dry())
            {
                echo 'Data with id:'.$id.' exist';
            }
            else echo 'Cursor is empty. Data with id:'.$id.' doesnt exist!';

            die();
        }
        else $f3->reroute('/');
```

how do I check if the ID exists without the error?

Comment: checking for null will always return false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `load()` method returns `false` when the data isn't found, then you should be checking for this before you try any further operations on this value.

I've also changed the test to be

```
if($data !== false) {
```

so that if your method returns some other value which looks like false (0, null etc), then this will ensure it only picks up `false`...

```
if(is_numeric($param['id'])) 
{
     $id = $param['id'];
     //check if data exist
     $data = $data->load($id);
     if($data !== false) {
         echo 'Data with id:'.$id.' exist';
     }
     else  {
         echo 'Cursor is empty. Data with id:'.$id.' doesnt exist!';
     }
     die();
}
else {
    $f3->reroute('/');
}
```

Comment: this is the way to go now. Checking if it is NULL also return false. thank you!